# AVL Tree with a int key and a string?

Tags: java, binary-search-tree, avl-tree

I currently have to implement a insert function for a AVL Tree that accepts an int key and a String string as arguments for a interface function.

```java
@Override
public void insert(int key, String string) {
    
}
```

Many tutorials, examples etc. use a `Node insert` function, however, i am a little bit lost on how to implement this on the given interface function.
How would i check for example if the key is already in the AVLTree? Would be awesome if anyone could guide me a little bit trough it so that i get a better idea on how to start.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include the full source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.
Also check the [help/on-topic] to see what questions you can ask.
Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236).
Please show your attempts you have tried and the problems/error messages you get from your attempts.

Comment: @Progman i stated already that i don't know how to even start, as it is a very odd setup. The provided code is all there is. There is not other source code, except for the interface function itself, hence why is asked the question...